# как переписать на функциональный стиль?

Tags: javascript

Как сделать в функиональном стиле. Функция возвращает true, если найдены limit совпадений. Ищет дубликаты, которые повторяются 2+ раза

```
export default function(array, currentdata, limit = 2) {
    const { ac, sub} = currentData;
    let counter = 0;
    for (let j = 0; j < array.length; j++) {
        if (counter >= limit) {
            return true;
        }
        if (array[j].type1 === ac && array[j].type2 === sub) {
            counter++;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: `return array.some(function(el){return (this.limit-=array[j].type1 === ac && array[j].type2 === sub)<1},{limit})`

Comment: а откуда array[j] ? может el?

Comment: Да, просто скопировал строку которая у тебя была, там el должен был быть

Answer (score 0):

Деструктуризацию параметра можно делать в самом объявлении:

`const { ac, sub} = currentData;` -> `function(array, { ac, sub}, limit = 2) {`

Для проверки удовлетворения элементов условию можно воспользоваться функцией [`.some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some)

При выполнении условия можно менять сам параметр `limit`, и останавливать поиск при достижении им значения `0`.

В итоге код функции может выглядеть так:

```
export default function(array, {ac, sub}, limit = 2) {
    return array.some(el=>(limit-=el.type1 === ac && el.type2 === sub)<1);
}
```